# Method remove/removeAll doesnt work correctly

Tags: java, hashmap, set, removeall

So im trying to outprint all pets which i made. Mainly i have problem with method *removeCats* , i think so..., How can i change my method removeCats to let it compile correctly?

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<Cat> cats = createCats();
        Set<Dog> dogs = createDogs();

        Set<Object> pets = join(cats, dogs);
        printPets(pets);

        removeCats(pets, cats);
        printPets(pets);
    }
```

**//2. Here i make method createCats, which must return 4 cats.**

```
public static Set<Cat> createCats()
{

    Set<Cat> result = new HashSet<Cat>();
    result.add(new Cat());
    result.add(new Cat());
    result.add(new Cat());
    result.add(new Cat());

    return result;
}
```

**//3. Here i make method createDogs, which must return 3 dogs.**

```
public static Set<Dog> createDogs()
{

    Set<Dog> resultD = new HashSet<Dog>();
    resultD.add(new Dog());
    resultD.add(new Dog());
    resultD.add(new Dog());

    return resultD;
}
```

**//4. Here i make method join, which must return all cats and dogs.**

```
public static Set<Object> join(Set<Cat> cats, Set<Dog> dogs)
{

    Set<Object> lol = new HashSet<Object>();
    lol.add(new Cat());
    lol.add(new Dog());

    return lol;
}
```

**//5. Method removeCats, must remove all cats**

```
public static void removeCats(Set<Object> pets, Set<Cat> cats)
{


    Iterator<Object> it = pets.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Object e = it.next();
             if(pets.containsAll(cats))
        pets.removeAll(cats);
    }
}
```

**//6. Method printPets, which must outprint on screen all animals, which he contains. Every animal on new line.**

```
public static void printPets(Set<Object> pets)
{

      for (Object s : pets){
          System.out.println(s);
      }
}

**//1. Inside class solution im making class cat and dog.**

public static class Cat{

}
public static class Dog{

}
```

Comment: Why use an iterator if you're not going to use it? You extract an object, e, but do nothing with it.

Comment: You haven't asked any question.

Comment: if i change it to e == cats , its also doesnt work corectly.

Comment: Why do you have the conditionals in `removeCats` at all? Unless the method is supposed to simply remove all cats, you need to explain its rules, and if it's supposed to simply remove all cats, all you need to do is `pets.removeAll(cats)`. (For what it's worth, `Cat` and `Dog` really ought to both subclass or implement `Pet`, but that's a different issue entirely.)

Comment: Do you expect a reference to Cat or Dog to be the same reference as a Set of Cats? (As this is what `==` does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems I see with your code:

- Your `removeCats` function is creating an iterator, not using it, then probably exploding with a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're removing things from the `pets` set while iterating over it.  Many of the other answers have pointed this out, and the best way to fix this is to replace this entire function with something like `pets.removeAll(cats);`. If you really must use an iterator for some reason, you should be iterating over `cats`, and calling `pets.remove(cat);`

Once this is fixed, you won't crash horribly. **However... `removeCats` will still not do what you expect, since none of the objects in `cats` are actually present in `pets`!**:

- Your `join` function is not doing what I'd expect it to do based on the method signature - it's not joining together the two sets, but instead discarding the inputs and creating a new list.  You probably want to do something like

  ```
  pets.addAll(cats);
  pets.addAll(dogs);
  ```

Once you fix this issue, your `printPets` function will work properly, and `removeCats` will actually have the right effect the way it is being called, since `pets` will actually contain `cats`, and not some new instances of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the Set while `iterating` it.Also there is no usage to iterate it.Simply remove the element if `containsAll` return `true`

```
 if(pets.containsAll(cats))
{
        pets.removeAll(cats);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in your `removeCats()` method that will cause an explosion: you are directly modifying a collection while iterating over it.

You can't add or remove elements while iterating. You may only call `iterator.remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void removeCats(Set<Object> pets, Set<Cat> cats) {
    pets.removeAll(cats);
}
```

Comment: it works, but its still compile incorrect output for me, maybe its something else =\

Comment: @Predict_it What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Predict_it Please edit your original question to include that. You should also give example input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the elements from Set, while iterating over it this will give you ConcurrentModificationException

what you can use like

```
pets.removeAll(cats);
```